# Convert multiple columns into rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How can I transform a file from one format to another: basically Week columns with unit sales become two columns with multiple rows and first few columns (with customer etc info)  have multiple rows for unit sales columns columns.

From

[image]

To [image]

I think there is a way to do it in Power Query? I am not a very advanced user so would greatly appreciate step by step how to do it :)

Unless there is a macro I can run?

Thanks

Ewa

Comment: In a word, unpivot.

Comment: will try, I think this is exactly what I did in the past and I could not remember :) I found tis and will try to follow. https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/unpivot-data-using-excel-power-query/

Comment: @Jeeped - unpivotting has worked, THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant
Dim b           As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim k           As Long
Dim x           As Long

a = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * 8, 1 To 6)
j = 1

For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    For k = 5 To UBound(a, 2)
        For x = 1 To 4
            b(j, x) = a(i, x)
        Next x
        b(j, 5) = a(1, k)
        b(j, 6) = a(i, k)
        j = j + 1
    Next k
Next i

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1")
    .Resize(, UBound(b, 2)).Value = Array("Account", "Code", "Product", "Segment", "Week", "Unit Sales")
    .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried unpivotting via power query and it is done :) Great to know there is also a macro that can do it. Thanks so so much for your swift replies. Much apprecieted